# Mapping myself form in Symfony2

Tags: php, forms, symfony, dictionary, doctrine

I'd like to map an entity of a form by myself. The thing is I'm working with 36 000 cities in a database and Doctrine doesn't return any result when I'm performing a request using findBy. But I set this up by writting my owns methods.

The problem is in a form I need to ask for a city through an entity field (because there are a lot of data, I'm using select2 with remote's data). So far, no problem but when I'm submiting the form, Symfony can't bind the city's id to a database entry because of the none result of the classic method of Doctrine.

So, my question is : How can I tell Symfony to use my repository's method instead of the Doctrine's one to bind my data?

Thank you very much ! And have a good day ;)

Comment: You would be better off figuring out the Doctrine issue.  Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The method `findBy()` request an array parameter sometimes people miss that:

```
$result = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
           ->getRepository("AcmeDemoBundle")->findBy(array(
               "city" => $city)
            );
```

If you want to use repository you just need to map it to your class:

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme/DemoBundle/Repository/CountryRepository")
*/
class Country
{ ... }
```

Then in

```
class CountryRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function getMySpecificCity($city)
    {
       $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c');
       $cities = $qb->select(*)
                    ->where("c.city =:city ")->setParameter('city', $city)
                    ->getQuery()
                    ->getResult();

       return $cities;
    }
    ...
}
```

So you can use it as follow:

```
$result = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
           ->getRepository("AcmeDemoBundle")->getMySpecificCity($city);
```